# Как найти минимум функции?

Tags: python, scipy

Мой код:

```
import math
from scipy import optimize


def f(x):
    return (math.sin(x/5) * math.exp(x/10) + 5 * math.exp(-x/2))

print optimize.minimize(f, [1,30])
```

Происходит ошибка. При использовании другой функции ошибки не происходит:

```
def f2(x):
    return .5*(1 - x[0])**2 + (x[1] - x[0]**2)**2

print optimize.minimize(f, [2, 2])
```

Чувствую, что причина в том, что math не работает со скалярами.
В чем может быть причина ошибки?

Comment: Опишите подробнее вашу проблему - приложите текст ошибки, исключения, полную трассировку, если применимо. В данном конкретном случае вам нужно переписать свою функцию на numpy, с использованием векторных, а не скалярных операций

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если говорить заочно, без лога, то проблема в том, что вы возврашаете вектора. Функция оптимизации же хочет от Вас чиселку, а не вектор.

В питоне, так, как делаете Вы, происходит следующее:

Пусть `x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, `y = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]`. В результате выполнения операции `*`, будет произведено почленное умножение вектора на вектор:

`z = x * y = [0 * 4, 1 * 3, 2 * 2, 3 * 1, 4 * 0] = [0, 3, 4, 3, 0]`

От Вас же хотят:

`z = (x, y) = [0 * 4 + 1 * 3 + 2 * 2 + 3 * 1 + 4 * 0] = 10`

Для этого нужно взять из `numpy` функцию `dot` и сделать так:

`numpy.dot(x, y)`.

В Вашем первом примере всё ломается, так как происходит работа с векторами (сложение и перемножение). Например:

`math.sin(x/5) * math.exp(x/10)`

В функцию `sin(x)` передаётся вектор и почленно вычисляется. После чего возвращается вектор. Во втором примере происходит работа с отдельными элементами вектора. Поэтому проблем не возникает.